# Select option in list

Tags: django

I have a list of tuples and I want to select one element from a `<select>` after displaying all choices.

I have 2 problems with that:

- I can't properly print my list of tuples, when I print it with django's for it doesn't display the right thing. Here is a part of my list :

  ```
  ISO639 = [
      ('ab', 'Abkhaz'),
      ('aa', 'Afar'),
      ('af', 'Afrikaans'),
      ('ak', 'Akan'),
      ('sq', 'Albanian'),
      ('am', 'Amharic'),
      ('ar', 'Arabic'),
      ]
  ```

  I'm getting it with:

  ```
  from ISO639 import ISO639 as languages

  def index(request):
      if request.method == 'POST':
          form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
      if form.is_valid():
              handleUploadFile(request.POST['name'] + '.json', request.FILES['docfile'], request.POST['language'])
              return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('fraud.api.views.index'))
      else:
          form = UploadFileForm()

      return render_to_response('api/index.html',
                                {'form': form, 'languages': languages},
                                context_instance=RequestContext(request))
  ```

  Display like this :

  ```
  <form action="{% url "upload" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="api">
      <select>
          {% for key, value in languages %}
          <option value={{ key }}> {{ value }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
      </select>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
  </form>
  ```

  And when I see the output, it's only printing 1 characters instead of the complete word in the list of option.
- I have a form with a attribut language and I don't know how to stock the value in that field.

  ```
  class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
      language = forms.CharField(max_length = 512)
  ```

I sure there is a better way to do that, I's quite new with django and open to any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: What is `languages` in that template, and how is it getting there? And why aren't you using the Django form? Apart from anything else, you're missing the `name` attribute in the `select` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to add logic to your template. Why don't you use a ChoiceField? See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield for the doc.

I'm not sure what you mean by "stock" in your second question. Do you want to store it in your database? If so you'll probably want to use a ModelForm.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement like this:

```
ISO639 = (
        ('ab', ('Abkhaz')),
        ('aa', ('Afar')),
        ..............
        ..............
        )

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    language = forms.ChoiceField(choices= ISO639)
```